# How to render an instance of a class in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a new instance of an object but I'm not sure how to call the render function or how to set the state from outside the object itself.

```
//App.js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DrawMessage from './components/DrawMessage'

function App() {

  var Draw = new DrawMessage();
  Draw.setState({
    test: 'THIS IS A NEW TEST!'
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
          <DrawMessage/>
          <Draw/>

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


//DrawMessage.js
import React from 'react'

class DrawMessage extends React.Component {

    constructor (props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            test: 'THIS IS A TEST!'
        }
    }

  render () {
    return <div className='message-box'>
      Hello {this.state.test}
    </div>
  }
}

export default DrawMessage
```

using the DrawMessage in the return yields "Hello THIS IS A TEST!" which is the default response

But if I was able to render the Draw i was expecting to see "Hello THIS IS A NEW TEST!" as i want to change the state of "test"

I am assuming that I cant call the render function from Draw the way i did and I don't think I am properly changing the state of test.

Comment: Your main <App/> component is a functional component you cant use setState, only with class based components. To pass data into a child component use props not state.

Comment: If you're new to react, I cannot stress how useful it is to take the official React tutorial/intro on the React website. It'll take maybe an hour of your life, two if you're playing around, and it literally teaches you every core mechanic and the general implementation rules and APIs that  you need to write perfectly fine React code on your own. Plus, it gives you a solid basis to come back to to look up how to do something when you forget.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans checking it out right now, seems more my speed! one question though, are fat arrows => like anonymous functions?

Comment: no, you can name them, the real difference between `function(...) { ...}` and `(...) => { ... }` is that with arrow notation the keyword `this` inside the function body points to whatever it was _when you declared the function_ rather than whatever it is by the time the function actually runs. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setState` on a child from a parent is not conventional React. I'd remove all of the following, and instead just invoke `DrawMessage` in the `return` of `App`:

```
var Draw = new DrawMessage();
Draw.setState({
  test: 'THIS IS A NEW TEST!'
});
```

One way to achieve your goal would be to set the state of `DrawMessage` in its constructor function, and then change it via `componentDidUpdate()` when the `props` passed from `App` change. If you're considering that route, ask yourself the following: does `DrawMessage` need to have its own state? If its state is often changed from the parent, it may be better served as part of `props`. React will re-render `DrawMessage` when `props` change.

[componentDidUpdate() docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Answer (score -1):

Via JSX: `var myTinyObject = <TinyObject prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2} />;`

Via React.createElement: `var myTinyObject = React.createElement(TinyObject, { prop1, prop2 }, null);`